# When using Log4Net to log to database, field names appearing instead of values

Tags: sql-server, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am having problems logging to my database using Log4Net.
I am not quite sure what to make of my results. I keep getting the field name when I should be getting the values of the fields.

The program is a SystemTray utility. I have set Log4Net up as follows.

In the Assembly:

```cs
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

In the Program.cs:

```cs
 private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

In the calling class:

```cs
public class HostManager
{

    #region constants

        protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HostManager));

        ...

        // Inside an event method:

          try
            {

                log.Info(new Log
                {   
                    CreateDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                    SystemUpTime = FormatUpTime(_states.TimeFromStart),
                    EmotivType = "boredom",
                    EmotivValue = _states.AffectivEngagementBoredomScore.ToString(),
                    EventTimer = _eventTimer,
                    SubEventTimer = _subEventTimer
                });


            }
```

The Log class is just a bunch of getter and setters of type string.

And, my app.config file with the log4net settings:

```xml
 <log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">

      <bufferSize value="1"/>
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      <connectionString value="Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=[MyDatabase]; Integrated Security=True;"/>

      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Session ([CreateDate], [SystemUpTime], [EmotivType], [EmotivValue], [EventTimer], [SubEventTimer]) 
                   VALUES (@createdate, @systemuptime, @emotivtype, @emotivvalue, @eventtimer, @subeventtimer)"/>

      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@createdate"/>
        <dbType value="DateTime"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>

       <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@systemuptime"/>
        <dbType value="DateTime"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
      </parameter>

     <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@emotivtype" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%emotivtype" />
  </layout>
  </parameter>

  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@emotivvalue"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%emotivvalue"/>
    </layout>
  </parameter>

      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@eventtimer"/>
        <dbType value="DateTime"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
      </parameter>

      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@subeventtimer"/>
        <dbType value="DateTime"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
      </parameter>

    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

The result is that the %emotivtype and %emotivalue always receive the field names:

```
ID  CreateDate  SystemUpTime    EmotivType  EmotivValue EventTimer  SubEventTimer
13547   17:06:56.787    17:06:56.787    emotivtype  emotivvalue 17:06:56.787    17:06:56.787
```

This seems like such a silly, fixable thing but it escapes me. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I have actually put decent effort into this so, whoever downvoted me, I wonder if they have put any research effort into reading my question. And, if so, I would like to know why I got a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

log4net does not know how to deal with your `Log` class and thus simply call `ToString()` on it... I guess you have two options.

First Option:
You make your class return the fields you are interested in some format that you parse in stored procedure on the database. E.g.

```
emotivtype|emotivevalue|other fields...
```

then you configure a single parameter for the stored procedure (you need one to parse the above string in the database.

```xml
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@emotivvalue"/>
    <dbType value="String"/>
    <size value="255"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
       <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

The obvious drawback is that you would not be able to get a decent output in a file or on a console. There are ways around this (custom layout converter) but I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Second Option:
You can use so called context properties (here is a good [tutorial](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-6-Log-Event-Context.aspx)). In particular look at the "Calculated Context Values". I am not sure what I should write about this... maybe if you have specific questions about it I can answer them.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I appreciate your answer. I have recently changed my appenders. When I was outputting my data to CSV using   <appender name="CsvFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender"> this worked perfectly. The LOG class did the trick. When I moved to  <appender name="SqlLogger" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender"> it started to fail. There seems to be a difference between how the two appenders are treating the LOG class. Why would that be?